# Which classical players' games should I check if I want to analyze positional players?

Tags: positional-play, famous-players

I am regularly analyzing games of grandmasters and now I want to check the classics. Who do you recommend to me as a positional player? Thanks.

Comment: I think this question, though good, can be improved by providing more information. For example, for a beginner studying Morphy games will provide a lot of positional insights, many times Morphy outplayed their opponents positionally before executing the attack. While a more advanced player who is interested in IQP positions would do better studying Botvinnik's games.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Smyslov
- Fischer
- Karpov
- Keres
- Anand
- Kramnik

Comment: I would add Petrosian to this mix, but otherwise fantastic list!

Answer (score 8):

1. Alexander Alekhine
2. Aron Nimzowitsch
3. Emanuel Lasker
4. Akiba Rubenstein
5. Siegbert Tarrasch
6. And many, many more! You can analyze some of their games [here!](https://thechessworld.com/articles/general-information/10-greatest-positional-masterpieces/)

Comment: I think Capablanca would be a good addition to this list.